# trying to parse json get error: use of undeclared type 'Foundation'

Tags: ios, json, swift, asynchronous

I have this strange error when I try to parse JSON. I do an api call via an async call, to get cities slug, with a completion handler:

```
//Load cities slug via api call
        let apiCall : webApi = webApi()

        apiCall.loadCitySlugs(){(success) in
            //Slug loaded in background
            //Call google api to compare the slug
            apiCall.compareSlugFromGoogleApi()
```

In the function `compareSlugFromGoogleApi()` there are some configuration things like the url of the async call, the post params, so nothing really relevant except the async call function:

```
/**
 Simple async call. Returns json NSMutableArray as AnyObject
 */
func asyncCall(url : String, completed : complHandlerAsyncCall)/* -> AnyObject*/{

    //Set async call params
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = postParam.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
            // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }


        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        asyncJson = responseString?.parseJSONString as! NSMutableArray

        flagAsyncCall = true // true if download succeed,false otherwise

        completed(success: flagAsyncCall!)

    }
    task.resume()
    //return json! as AnyObject
}
```

In the async call function, I call to an extension `parseJSONString` that return a json object easy to parse:

```
extension NSString
{
    var parseJSONString: AnyObject?
    {
        let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

        if let jsonData = data
        {
            // Will return an object or nil if JSON decoding fails
            do
            {
                let message = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options:.MutableContainers)
                if let jsonResult = message as? NSMutableArray
                {

                    return jsonResult //Will return the json array output
                }
                else
                {
                    return nil
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("An error occurred: \(error)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Lossless conversion of the string was not possible
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where I'm having a problem with the Google call. Everything looks more or less ok, but it returns a nil value from the extension and then, back in the async call, it throws me this error:

[image]

still the response object is not empty:

[image]

Comment: Why do you declare the computed variable `parseJSONString` as `AnyObject` although it returns always `NSMutableArray` on success? The strong type concept of Swift highly recommends to be as specific as possible.

Comment: because otherwise I cannot return a nil value.Nil is incompatible with return type NSMutableArray.I did it the way you said but it's the same. I have to declare NSMutableArray optional (?)

Comment: Use native Swift collection types. They make things much easier.

Comment: yes that's a good advice, but I still don't know why a good json crashes in a function supposed to parse any good json. It breaks all the logic of my program and force me to change a lot of things that were set and working.

Comment: Your code is very confusing. For example: you're receiving JSON *data*, then you're decoding it as a *String* only to encode it to *data* again before decoding it to an object with NSJSONSerialization! It should be just data->object... And the whole logic is unnecessary convoluted anyway, making the code hard to debug. You should work on fixing all these problems before coding further. Never hesitate to restart from scratch when necessary. :) And yes, you should really use Swift objects, you have no reason to use NSArray or NSDictionary here.

Comment: Also try to pass everything a function needs as a param. We have no idea what `flagAsyncCall` `asyncJson` and `postParam` are, how they are declared, if they have values,... It also makes it impossible for us to grab your code and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDictionary` instead of `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: it doesn't even parse the first json with NSMutableDictionary

Comment: @user3033437 My mistake - should be NSDictionary. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks, and by the way, it's not me who downvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error because `parseJSONString` returns nil, and when you unwrap that `!` it crashes. You should check if `parseJSONString` returns non nil. `if let parsed = parseJSONString { do something }`